# Adding element to array that has v-model causes duplicate

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, v-model

I've got a list of text input-fields created through a v-for with a `v-model` to an array. I want to add elements to the array, and thus creating another input-field.

So far all works. The problem is that the new input-fields are somehow all assigned the same index (?) or something else is happening to cause them to display the same value.

I've made [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gnopps/67na8y2u/25/) to showcase what I mean. **If you press the button twice and then try to edit one of the new input-boxes, then all the new input-boxes will get the edited value. I'd want only the edited input-box to show the input value.**

I guess there is something I am overlooking here. Is there anyone who can help with this please?

Javascript:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [{name: "one", id: 0}],
    template: {
        name: "two",
        id: 2,
    },
  },
   methods: {
    addRow: function(){
    this.items.push(this.template);
    this.items[this.items.length - 1].id = Math.random();
    }
  }
  })
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(item,index) in items" :key="item.id">
  <input v-model="item.name">
  </div>
  <button v-on:click="addRow">
  Add row
  </button>
  <div>Array content: {{items}}</div>
</div>
```

Usage:
[screenshot of what i'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQOr0.gif)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
   this.items.push({
            name: "two",
             id: 2,
           });
```

instead of `this.items.push(this.template)` because `template` property is reactive and it will affect other properties that use it

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tcafpr4n/)

Comment: Ah, of course: I forgot that with objects you don't clone, you just reference to the same object. Thank you for your help!
I guess this means that I can't have a template-object but must create it on-the-fly in the function.?

Answer (score 8):

The problem here is that with `array.push(declaredObject)` you are adding a reference of `template` so every change will be reflected in all its references.

You must add a new object with the same properties, you can achieve that in many ways, the more common is `Object.assign({}, this.template)` and the newest one is **[Destructuring objects](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/)** `{...this.template}`. so in your case It should be `this.items.push({...this.template})`

Comment: Destructuring the template object seems to work great, thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped !

Comment: Thank you. You have saved my day.